NetworkStream.Readを連続して実行すると途中でSystem.IndexOutOfRangeExceptionが発生することがある
Connectを一度実行したあとに、同じNetworkStreamを使いまわして複数回NetworkStream.Readを実行すると以下の例外が発生することがあります。

例外がスローされました: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' (Common.dll の中)
例外がスローされました: 'System.IO.IOException' (System.Net.Sockets.dll の中)

例外の内部メッセージをcatch文で出力したところ以下にようでした。

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): 接続済みの呼び出し先が一定の時間を過ぎても正しく応答しなかったため、接続できませんでした。または接続済みのホストが応答しなかったため、確立された接続は失敗しました。
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)

NetworkStreamを使いまわしたいとき下記のコードでは問題があるでしょうか。
using var client = new TcpClient();

try
{
    await client.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 55100);
    var ns = client.GetStream();
    ns.ReadTimeout = 1000;
    ns.WriteTimeout = 1000;
    char prefix = (char)0x02;
    char suffix = (char)0x0d;
    int size = 1024;

    foreach (var command in commands)
    {
        byte[] _byteBuffer = new byte[size];
        Debug.WriteLine("ns.Write Start.");
        ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{prefix}{command}{suffix}"));

        Debug.WriteLine("ns.Read Start.");
        var _recieveSize = ns.Read(_byteBuffer);
        StringBuilder receiveBuffer = new();
        receiveBuffer.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_byteBuffer[.._recieveSize]));
        var _reply = Regex.Replace(receiveBuffer.ToString(), $"[{prefix}{suffix}]", "");

        Debug.WriteLine("Command=" + command + " Reply=" + _reply);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}


ご回答ありがとうございました。
設計を見直したところ原因がわかり不具合現象を解消できました。
クライアントからサーバに接続終了コマンドを送信することで解決しました。
サーバはAcceptするたびに受信用の無限ループのスレッドを作成するのですが
クライアントがConnectをクローズするとそのスレッドは不要になるにも関わらず生き残り続けていました。クライアントからサーバに無限ループ終了を指示するようにしたところ解決しました。

もちろん単純なネットワークエラーの可能性もありますが、それとは別に

ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{prefix}{command}{suffix}"));


このメソッドが完了したからといって、相手に届いた・届けられたという保証はありません。送信バッファ内で滞留している可能性があります。
その場合、通信相手はデータを受け取っていないのですから応答を送ってこないという状況も当然あり得ます。
とりあえず TcpClient.NoDelayプロパティを設定することで、バッファ内での滞留を避けることができます。より厳密にはTCPプロトコル仕様とWindows Sockets仕様を理解し細かなオプション指定を行う必要があります。

エラーメッセージにあるように、以下のところでタイムアウトしていると思われます。
var _recieveSize = ns.Read(_byteBuffer);

NetworkStream.ReadTimeout のデフォルトは、Infinite ですが、あえてタイムアウト値(1000 ミリ秒)を設定しているので、想定された動作となるのではないでしょうか？
